# Logstash pipeline grok pattern for Java logs only picks up DEBUG messages

Tags: spring-boot, logstash, logback, logstash-grok

So I have this very simple pipeline:

```
input { ... }
filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} %{LOGLEVEL:level} (?<logmessage>.*)" ]
    add_tag => [ "java" ]
  }
}
output { ... }
```

I'd like to tag matching messages as "java", and the grok pattern is there to extract the loglevel in case of Java messages and to get rid of the timestamp.

However, it only recognizes DEBUG logs, nothing else, without exception. So this log is correctly parsed and tagged when viewed on Kibana:

```
2021-07-07 12:34:56.789 DEBUG 1 --- [ scheduling-1] blah blah
```

but this one is not:

```
2021-07-07 12:34:56.789 INFO 1 --- [ scheduling-1] blah blah
```

Kibana's grok debugger works for the pattern in both cases.

Already tried some more or less complicated grok patterns to match the message better. Also tried to define the log *level* as WORD type. It puzzles me beyond imagination.

Comment: Probably the messages with INFO are not the same as the ones with the debug, could have an extra space for example. Please update your question with a real example of each message, INFO and DEBUG, also shar your input filter.

Comment: I agree with @leandrojmp - the config and the examples in the question fail to show the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did copy these out of Kibana with very minimal changes, but the commenters were on the right track. I should have looked for them in the originating apps, not on Kibana, since at a certain step, the extra whitespaces were trimmed from the log messages.

So what can be seen in the question was initially printed with some padding:

```
2021-07-07 12:34:56.789 DEBUG 1 --- [        asd-1] blah blah
2021-07-07 12:34:56.789  INFO 1 --- [ scheduling-1] blah blah
```

For future reference, I circumvented the problem by replacing the literal whitespaces in the pattern with a selector that matches any number of them:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}(?<logmessage>.*)" ]
  }
}
```